# Submitted data into a single var

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes, unique-key

I am passing some values out of a form into a function so it is ready for database insertion.
The function theoretically works fine. However, it misses a unique value that puts me in trouble afterward.
I'm trying to generate a unique ID based on the data that is submitted to the database.
I want to generate the ID like this:

> var mystringId = prodID+'{'+selectId+'}'+selectedOptionValue;

Should output for example: **20{100}3{200}6**.
In my sample it generates above the following:

**20{100}3**

**20{200}6**

because of the `each();`

```
$("#submitme").live('click', function() {
//var mystringId = prodID;
    $('select').each(function() {
        var addedOn = new Date();
        var selectName= $(this).attr("name");        
        var selectId= $(this).attr("id");
        var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.val();
        var selectedOptionText = selectedOption.text();

        var mystringId = prodID+'{'+selectId+'}'+selectedOptionValue;

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO xxxxx mystringId');

        });

    });
    $.mobile.changePage( "#cart", { transition: "slideup"} );
    });
```

Comment: If you have two select elements you want the mystringID to be for example `20{100}3{200}6` for both of them?

Comment: pls elaborate your expectations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather from your question, you can simply do a each loop before your current code to generate the `mystringId` in the format your looking for to use inside your code.

**Code**

```
$("#submitme").live('click', function() {
    var mystringId = prodID;

    $('select').each(function() {
        var selectId= $(this).attr("id");
        var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.val();

        mystringId += '{' + selectId + '}' + selectedOptionValue;
    });

    $('select').each(function() {
        var addedOn = new Date();
        var selectName= $(this).attr("name");
        var selectId= $(this).attr("id");
        var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.val();
        var selectedOptionText = selectedOption.text();

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO xxxxx mystringId');
        });
    });

    $.mobile.changePage( "#cart", { transition: "slideup"} );
});
```

**Results**

The results would be mystringId starting off with the value of prodID `mystringId = 20`

The first iteration of the loop would append `{100}3` resulting in `mystringId = 20{100}3`

The second iteration of the loop would append `{200}6` resulting in `mystringId  = 20{100}3{100}6`

Comment: Thanks!!!! and i was thinking so complicated.i think you deserve more credit couse of explaining your answer verry detailed.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.